# Parse Inverse Relationship in Javascript (whereEqualTo)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, nosql

Im using parse with JS and i'm trying to do a reverse relationship...

I have the follow tables..

`User`

`Offers`

And the `User` table has a `relationship` column to relate a user to an offer and I have two types of relationships `used_offers` and `saved_offers` both of which tie the `user` to a `offer`.

I decided to put the relationship on the `User` table instead of the `Offers` table so that the `ACL` permission mean that only that user can read the relationship rather than anyone being able to read the relationship on a specific offer.

So... my question is... I am trying to list all the offers but I also want to join (if it exists) a relationship, ie so I know the in data returned it the `offer` is `saved` or `used`.

My current code looks like this...

```
//Get offer object and create query
var Offer = Parse.Object.extend("Offer");
var offerQuery = new Parse.Query(Offer);

var user = Parse.User.current();     //Get user object//Get user object
console.log(user);     //Check user object exists (ie logged in)
offerQuery.whereEqualTo("saved_offers", user);     //Get user object//Show relationships
offerQuery.include(["user"]);     //Get user object//Return the user data also
offerQuery.find({
     success: function(object) {
         console.log(object);
     },
     error: function(error) {
         console.log(error);
     }
});
```

I get an error of... `uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Which im sure is related to the line...

`offerQuery.whereEqualTo("saved_offers", user);`

Super appreciate any help here, Parse is great but i cannot find specific documenation to use `whereEqualTo` (if this is the write command to call) in JS.

Many thanks!

Comment: It should be `equalTo` instead of `whereEqualTo`.

Comment: @eth3lbert make your comment an answer. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It should be [equalTo](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#equalTo) instead of `whereEqualTo`.

Comment: Looking at the last exmaple at https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#manytomany it uses whereEqualTo for inverse relationships.

Comment: @MattTheNinja yes, but it's for android instead of js.